# PHP How to pass variables through a link to the next php file

Tags: php

```
echo "<td>" . 
    "<a href='approve_mem.php?id=$row['member_id']'>Approve</a>" . " " . 
    '<a href="disapprove_mem.php?id=$row[member_id]">Disapprove</a>' .
"</td>";
```

This is my code but the value of id does not get passed instead it gets passed like id=$row['member_id'] as it is, and when I echoed the id variable it got printed like $row['member_id']

Comment: please read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (twice)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building HTML strings in PHP, I recommend you only switch to the PHP context when required, eg

```
<td>
    <a href="approve_mem.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['member_id']) ?>">Approve</a>
    <a href="disapprove_mem.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['member_id']) ?>">Disapprove</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is part of a database query. You have to seperate the data from the string in this instance. This can be written two ways:

```
 <td>
   <a href='approve_mem.php?id=<?php echo $row['member_id']; ?>'>Approve</a> <a href="disapprove_mem.php?id=<?php echo $row['member_id']; ?>">Disapprove</a>
 </td>
```

------------- OR -------------

```
 echo "<td><a href='approve_mem.php?id=".$row['member_id']."'>Approve</a> <a href='disapprove_mem.php?id=".$row['member_id']."'>Disapprove</a></td>";
```

Comment: depending on what you are passing (number or string), you may have to url encode the string by using: urlencode($string)

Comment: As this is an HTML document, that should be HTML encode, not URL encode

Comment: to pass any type of variable though a url you have to use urlencode and then on the other page you use urldecode to resort it back to the original. htmlspecialchars changes html characters, example: < to &lt;. This will break the get variable at the &. Where urlencode changes them to %2F (/) or their equilivent that does not break the get variables. That is why you would use urlencode and urldecode

Comment: fair point. You should probably use both encoding schemes in that case, one to protect the HTML document from quotes and markup and the other to not destroy the URL with ampersands

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<td>" . 
"<a href='approve_mem.php?id=".$row['member_id']."'>Approve</a>" . " " . 
'<a href="disapprove_mem.php?id='.$row['member_id'].'">Disapprove</a>' ."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to:-

```
echo "<td>" . 
    "<a href='approve_mem.php?id={$row['member_id']}'>Approve</a>" . " " . 
    "<a href='disapprove_mem.php?id={$row['member_id']}'>Disapprove</a>" .
"</td>";
```

Notice the use of curly braces and the change of quotes used in the second line. Also you hadn't quoted member_id in your second use of $row['member_id']

Also take note of Dagon's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

change that to this:

```
  echo "<td><a href=\"approve_mem.php?id=".$row['member_id']."\">Approve</a>
  <a href=\"disapprove_mem.php?id=".$row['member_id']."\">Disapprove</a></td>";
```

or

```
 <td>
       <a href='approve_mem.php?id=<?=$row['member_id']?>'>Approve</a>
       <a href='disapprove_mem.php?id=<?=$row['member_id']?>'>Disapprove</a>
 </td>
```